# Creating react util function with React elements

Tags: reactjs

I created some util functions in my react application. I organized them in several files and in the common.js file, I inserted these functions. I want to know if Im doing this right. When creating util functions, importing React from 'react' and use react elements, is this a good practice? OR, util functions should not have elements inside them?

```
import React from 'react';

export const isEmpty = value => { 
   return (
      value === undefined ||
      value === null ||
      (typeof value === 'object' && Object.keys(value).length === 0) ||
      (typeof value === 'string' && value.trim().length === 0)
   );
}

export const setTableHeaders = headers => {
   const columnNames = headers.map(header => { 
      return <th key={header}>{header}</th>;
   });

   return <tr>{columnNames}</tr>;
}
```

Comment: Technically `setTableHeaders` isn't a util in your code instead its more of a functional component. However its completely up to you whether you want to have the utils file process and Return React elements and there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: BTW, Recently I keep seeing arrow functions assigned to `const`s instead of a `function` declaration, where does this style come from?

Comment: It depends on the size, complexity and expected lifespan of your project, but I would say that I usually carefully try to write React components every time React is being used (such as `setTableHeaders`). React introduces a wonderfully simple interface, so why not use it as much as possible? In short, most things that requires `import ... from 'react'` should be a component in its own right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good practice! Depends!

If the util function really require to import react and need the components, then Yes.

But the function `setTableHeaders` isn't really a util function as far as i can understand.

So, it would be good to understand the difference between whether the function is really a util function or not.